# Move one letter words to next line

Tags: html, text, move, words, word-wrap

I have a responsive webpage. Is it possible to automatically move one letter words at the end of the line to next line.

**Example:**

A picture is worth
a thousand words.

**instead of:**

A picture is worth a
thousand words.

Comment: you will have to check the line content if there are 1 character words and if yes, you place a `\n` before it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly but works. Just change the values in words and elements array to your needs

```
function removeSingleCharLineBreak(){
var words = ['a', 'i', 's', 'z', 'v', 'k', 'o', 'u', 
    'A', 'I', 'S', 'Z', 'V', 'K', 'O', 'U', '€',
    'na', 'za', 'do', 'Na', 'Za', 'Do',
    ];

var elements = ['p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'li', 'td', 'td'];

$.each(words, function(index, word){

    var regex = new RegExp(" " + word + " ", "g");

    $.each(elements, function(index, element){

        $(element + ':contains( ' + word + ' )').each(function(){

            if (word == '€') 
            {
                $(this).html(
                    $(this).html().replace(regex, '&nbsp;' + word + '&nbsp;')
                );       
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).html(
                    $(this).html().replace(regex, ' ' + word + '&nbsp;')
                );                    
            }

        });

    });

});
```

}

Comment: I can't belive that it's so complicated, thought that there will be some css which is doing this!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, yes. One way to do it would be with a `textContent.replace(/( \S) /g, "$1\n")` and the CSS property [`white-space: pre-line`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#propdef-white-space). Note that `\w` is not an appropriate matcher for natural language letters in JavaScript, as it only matches ASCII alphanumeric characters.

You could also prevent line-breaks from occurring after one-letter words by replacing the whitespace between them and the next word with a non-breakable space with `textContent.replace(/( \S) /g, "$1\xa0")`

Comment: Hi @Touffy, where to place this code (?): textContent.replace(/( \S) /g, "$1\xa0")

Comment: *textContent* should refer to the `textContent` property of the HTML element whose text you want to alter. If you want to do it everywhere blindly, you'll need to write some code that traverses your document tree and applies the text replacement to every text node instead.